# Json to Jstree - Selected Node issue

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I build a Json that looks like that:

[{"data": {"title": "Part A", "attr": {"id": "II", "title": "Products"}}, "state": "closed", "children": [{"data": {"title": "Part AA", "attr": {"id": "12", "title": "Chapter22"}}, "state": "closed", "children": [{"data": {"title": "Chapter B", "attr": {"id": "25", "title": "Apples -"}}, "state": "**selected**", "children": [{"data": {"title": "Oranges", "attr": {"id": "28", "title": "Red"}}, "metadata": {"id": "132", "description": "MyApples", "fullClassification": "Des"}}], "metadata": {"id": "155", "description": "Toys -", "fullClassification": "Des2"}}], "metadata": {"id": "12333", "description": "Des5", "fullClassification": "0800000000"}}], "metadata": {"id": "243", "description": "Des34", "fullClassification": "Des324"}}]

And I transfer this  Json to a Jstree: (here is the ui plugin that deals with selection)

```
$("#jstree01").jstree({
        "plugins": ["themes", "ui"],
        "themes": {
            "theme": "default-rtl",
            "dots": false,
            "icons": false
        },
        "ui": {
            "select_limit": 1,
            "selected_parent_close": false,
            "select_prev_on_delete": false,
        },
```

**The result:** I have a valid tree, but no node is selected.
How do I select a node via Json that is transffered to Jstree?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

Hi,
you have to set the state parameter in this way:

```
state: {
    opened    : boolean  // is the node open
    disabled  : boolean  // is the node disabled
    selected  : boolean  // is the node selected
},
```